# Loot condition for death by fall damage in forge for 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am creating a Forge mod for 1.12.2, and I need a certain item to be dropped when a pig dies of fall damage. I have already found how to change loot tables and such, I just need the LootCondition class for fall damage. My onLootTableLoad function:

```java
@SubscribeEvent
    public void onLootTableLoad(LootTableLoadEvent event){
        if (event.getName().equals(LootTableList.ENTITIES_PIG)) {
            final LootPool main = event.getTable().getPool("main");

            if (main != null) {

                // pool2.addEntry(new LootEntryItem(ITEM, WEIGHT, QUALITY, FUNCTIONS, CONDITIONS, NAME));
                main.addEntry(new LootEntryItem(new ItemYeetiumNugget("yeetium_nugget"), 1, 0, new LootFunction[0], new LootCondition[] {<Loot condition here>}, "yeetstick:yeetium_nugget_drop"));
            }
        }
    }
```

The loot condition would go in `<Loot condition here>`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using loot table loading for this was inadequate, so I switched to subscribing to the LivingDrops event. This is the revised code (completely different):

```java
@SubscribeEvent
    public void onLivingDrops(LivingDropsEvent event){
        if (event.getEntityLiving() instanceof EntityPig){
            if(event.getSource() == DamageSource.FALL){
                event.getDrops().add(new EntityItem(event.getEntity().world, event.getEntity().posX,event.getEntity().posY, event.getEntity().posZ, new ItemStack(new ItemYeetiumNugget("yeetium_nugget"))));
            }
        }
    }
```